Gaussian Quadrature known Nodes
I know that for the Gaussian interpolatory quadrature with $2$ nodes, you can approximate the integral as $\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx \approx f(x_0) w_0 + f(x_1) w_1$.
To maximise the degree of exactness you can form $4$ equations starting from $\int_{a}^{b} 1 dx = w_0 + w_1$ up to $\int_{a}^{b} x^3 dx = x_0^3w_0 + x_1^3w_1$
Solving in the case $a=-1$,$b=1$ gives $x_0 = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}, x_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},w_0=1,w_1=1$, so $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x) dx \approx f(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}) + f(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$
Is this correct thinking so far?
However, Say if I am told the nodes $x_0=2$ and $x_1=5$, can I just sub this into the following equations, where this time we only have $2$ equations, given by $\int_{-1}^{1}1 dx = w_0 + w_1$ and $\int_{-1}^{1}xdx=2w_0+5w_1$, giving $w_0=\frac{10}{3}$ and $w_1=\frac{-4}{3}$, so $\int_{-1}^{1}1 dx = w_0 + w_1 \approx \frac{10}{3}f(2) - \frac{4}{3}f(5)$
Is this correct?
